# How to parametrize in batch file - Want to open a putty session with user name & pwd parameterized through an external text file

Tags: batch-file

Below is the batch program I have currently which can read two lines from a text file 
Want to create a batch file which helps to create a putty session with user name & pwd parameterized through an external text file?

```
@echo off    
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion    
set L=1    
for /F "delims=" %%a in (hi.txt)     
do    
(    
  set line=%%a    
  echo !line!    
  set  /a  L=!L!+1    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, given lines `1` & `2` of `hi.txt` as below:

```
Dinesh
pA55w0rd
```

The following should `Set` variables for those two values:

```bat
@Echo Off
<"hi.txt" (Set /P "user="
    Set /P "pass=")
Echo("%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\putty.exe" %user%@somewhere.com -pw %pass%
Pause
```

*Change the file name `hi.txt`, the location `%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\` and the host `somewhere.com` as necessary.

If you're happy with the screen output, remove `Echo(` from line `4` and optionally delete line `5`.*